solr split the shard data equally in to 2 shard
I have a collection with compositeId router with 5 shards.
One of the shard contains around 20 million documents.
is there a way to split the shard further into 2 shards having roughly equal documents? (10 million + 10 million documents)?
details of the collection

Have you looked into the shard splitting:
https://solr.apache.org/guide/6_6/collections-api.html#CollectionsAPI-splitshard
